# insertion sort in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, scipy, insertion-sort

Is there a insertion sort somewhere in numpy? I require a argsort for my array but the builtin quick,merge and heap are not suitable for nearly sorted array.

Comment: Could you explain why the standard sorting methods are 'not suitable'?

Comment: @JoshAdel [These animations](https://www.toptal.com/developers/sorting-algorithms/nearly-sorted-initial-order) nicely show that the available algorithms quicksort, mergesort, heapsort all have higher complexity then insertion sort for nearly sorted data.

Comment: There's my positive answer now. Would you mind to accept it?

Answer (score 3):

From the [numpy 1.17.0 release notes](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/release/1.17.0-notes.rst#timsort-has-replaced-mergesort-as-the-stable-sorting-implementation):

> Timsort has been implemented and is now used in place of mergesort. [...] Timsort features improved performace on already or nearly sorted data and performs like mergesort on random data.

As of the time of this writing, NumPy 1.17.0 is not out yet, but when it is, you will be able to select Timsort by specifying `kind='stable'` or `kind='mergesort'` in a `sort` call:

```
sorted = numpy.sort(unsorted, kind='stable')
```

This satisfies the "fast on nearly-sorted data" role you wanted to use insertion sort for, while also taking advantage of other order in the input and having much better worst-case behavior than insertion sort.

Earlier numpy versions [do not have a fast method for nearly sorted data](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12186).

Comment: Thanks to @user2357112 for improving my answer.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `numpy.searchsorted` in conjunction with `numpy.insert`:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html

Comment: I think `searchsorted` needs a fully sorted list and not just "nearly sorted".

Comment: @shang: Certainly JoshAdel meant that one can implement insertion sort by iteratively calling these two methods on an increasing subset.